# What is the correct verb for "packing up?"

Tags: verbs

I am not sure what verb I would use for "packing up" (e.g. Packing clothes into a suitcase). Would I use the verb 詰める {つめる}, which is "to stuff into?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would use 詰める. (you can also use variants such as 詰め込む)

You can get a lot of example sentences on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&ei=G4UZXLjfDsWYa8-qhMAM&q=%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AB%E8%A9%B0%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B&oq=%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%B0%E3%81%AB%E8%A9%B0%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i5i30.35407.37353..38107...0.0..0.154.1636.6j9......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i4j0i67j0i5i4i30j0i5i4i10i30.m3Wngnb51Hw), too.

[This one](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E8%A9%B0%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B) is pretty useful as well.

Comment: Can you also use 詰める for in general packing up? (for example, packing up and checking out of a hotel).

Comment: @Joshuap88 In that case, 荷造りをする as istrasci mentioned would be better. Ex: 荷造りをしてチェックアウトをする

Answer (score 1):

[荷造]{に・づく}り specifically means "packing up".  The verb would be 荷造り（を）する.